# LWJGL texture only loading as a 1D line

Tags: kotlin, opengl, lwjgl, texture-mapping

**EDIT**:
I have disabled the projection and view matrix for testing purposes and it works now. I have no idea what went wrong but I'll look into it.

I'm relatively new to LWJGL and am currently trying to load a texture.
I can see the texture but it's only a vertical line instead of a quad/square.
I followed [this](https://ahbejarano.gitbook.io/lwjglgamedev/chapter7) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7i9oXEoe86Q) tutorial. I have a different structure in my project and tried to move functions around so it better fits my structure. I checked if the UV coordinates in each vertex correct and they are (technically the image is rotated but it definitely isn't mapped as a single line). I was able to render a square with a color before. I also enabled OpenGL Debug logs and the messages I got were:

```
[LWJGL] OpenGL debug message
    ID: 0x20071
    Source: API
    Type: OTHER
    Severity: NOTIFICATION
    Message: Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 2 (bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STATIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.
[LWJGL] OpenGL debug message
    ID: 0x20071
    Source: API
    Type: OTHER
    Severity: NOTIFICATION
    Message: Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 1 (bound to GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (0), GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (1), GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (2), and GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I looked through the tutorial code and checked whether my code runs all the OpenGL stuff that the tutorial does.

This is the code in the relevant classes: (It might be easier to just clone the repository and open it in an IDE)

**Core**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window.DebugScene
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window.Window
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

object Core {

    lateinit var window: Window
    var isShutdownScheduled = false

    fun run() {
        this.init()
        do {
            this.loop()
        } while (!this.isShutdownScheduled)
        this.close()
    }

    private fun init() {
        Thread.currentThread().name = "main"

        this.window = Window(1920, 1080, "The Untitled Game: ")
        this.window.scene = DebugScene()
    }

    private fun loop() = this.window.update()

    private fun close() {
        this.window.destroy()
        exitProcess(0)
    }

    fun shutdown() {
        this.isShutdownScheduled = true
    }
}
```

**Window**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.Core
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.util.Time
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

class Window(
    width: Int,
    height: Int,
    title: String
) {
    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger()!!
    var glfw: Long = -1
        private set
    var title: String = title
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                logger.debug("Changed window title from '$field' to '$value'.")
                field = value
                GLFW.glfwSetWindowTitle(this.glfw, value)
            }
        }
    var width: Int = width
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                GLFW.glfwSetWindowSize(this.glfw, value, this.height)
                GL30.glViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
            }
            field = value
        }
    var height: Int = height
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                GLFW.glfwSetWindowSize(this.glfw, this.width, value)
                GL30.glViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
            }
            field = value
        }

    var scene: Scene? = null
        set(value) {
            field?.stop()
            logger.debug("Switching scene from '${field?.name}' to '${value?.name}'.")
            field = value
            value?.preInit()
            value?.init(this)
            value?.postInit()
        }

    private var beginTime = 0.0
    private var endTime = 0.0
    private var dTime = 0.0
    private var fpsUtil = 0.0

    init {
        this.title = title + randomTitleSuffix()

        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set()

        if (!GLFW.glfwInit()) throw IllegalStateException("GLFW could not be initialized!")

        GLFW.glfwDefaultWindowHints()
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW.GLFW_FALSE)
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE)
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_MAXIMIZED, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE)
        if (GLFW_DEBUG) GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE)

        this.glfw = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(
            this.width, this.height, this.title,
            MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL
        )
        if (this.glfw == MemoryUtil.NULL) throw IllegalStateException("Failed to create window!")

        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(this.glfw)
        GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1)
        GL.createCapabilities()

        if (GLFW_DEBUG) GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback()

        GLFW.glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(this.glfw) { _: Long, newWidth: Int, newHeight: Int ->
            this.width = newWidth
            this.height = newHeight
            logger.debug("Window '${this.title}' resized to width=$newWidth and height=$newHeight.")
        }

        GLFW.glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(this.glfw) { Core.shutdown() }

        GLFW.glfwShowWindow(this.glfw)
    }

    companion object {
        fun randomTitleSuffix(): String {
            val url = this::class.java.getResource("/assets/title-suffixes.txt")!!
            var suffix: String
            do suffix = url.readText().lines().random()
            while (suffix.isBlank())
            return suffix
        }

        const val GLFW_DEBUG = true
        const val DEBUG_FPS_UPDATE_DELAY = 1
    }

    fun update() {
        GLFW.glfwPollEvents()
        if (this.dTime >= 0) {
            if (this.scene != null) GL11.glClearColor(
                this.scene!!.background.red,
                this.scene!!.background.green,
                this.scene!!.background.blue,
                this.scene!!.background.alpha
            ) else GL11.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        }

        this.scene?.preRender()
        this.scene?.render()
        this.scene?.postRender()

        GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(this.glfw)

        this.endTime = Time.now()
        this.dTime = this.endTime - this.beginTime
        this.beginTime = this.endTime
        if (this.fpsUtil == .0 || (this.fpsUtil + DEBUG_FPS_UPDATE_DELAY < this.endTime)) {
            this.fpsUtil = this.endTime
            logger.debug("FPS: ${(1f / this.dTime).roundToInt()}")
        }
    }

    fun close() = GLFW.glfwSetWindowShouldClose(this.glfw, true)

    fun destroy() {
        GLFW.glfwDestroyWindow(this.glfw);

        GLFW.glfwTerminate();
        GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(null)?.free();
    }
}
```

**Scene**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.listener.KeyHandler
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.listener.MouseHandler
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.camera.Camera
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.Renderer
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.ShaderProgram
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.util.Color
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.objects.GameObject
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import java.io.File

@Suppress("LeakingThis")
abstract class Scene(
    val name: String,
    val shader: ShaderProgram = ShaderProgram(name),
    var background: Color = Color.WHITE
) {

    var window: Window? = null
        private set
    val camera = Camera(0f, 0f)
    val mouseHandler = MouseHandler(this)
    val keyHandler = KeyHandler(this)
    val renderer = Renderer(this)
    private val objs = mutableListOf<GameObject>()

    open fun preInit() {}

    open fun init(window: Window) {
        this.window = window
        this.mouseHandler.enable()
        this.keyHandler.enable()
    }

    open fun postInit() {
        this.shader.link()
        GL30.glEnable(GL30.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    }

    open fun preRender() = this.shader.use()

    open fun render() {
        if (this.validate()) this.renderer.render()
    }

    open fun postRender() = this.shader.detach()


    open fun stop() {
        this.mouseHandler.disable()
        this.keyHandler.disable()
    }

    fun loadVertex(file: File) = this.shader.loadVertex(file)

    fun loadVertex(file: String) = this.loadVertex(File(file))

    fun loadFragment(file: File) = this.shader.loadFragment(file)

    fun loadFragment(file: String) = this.shader.loadFragment(File(file))

    open fun validate() = this.shader.validate()

    open fun validateQuiet() = this.shader.validateQuiet() == 0

    open fun addObject(obj: GameObject) {
        this.objs.add(obj)
        this.renderer.add(obj)
    }

    fun uploadCameraDataToGPU() = this.camera.uploadToGPU(this.shader)
}
```

**DebugScene**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.texture.Texture
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.util.Color
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.util.Time
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.objects.GameObject
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.objects.components.SpriteRenderer

class DebugScene : Scene("Debug Scene!", background = Color.WHITE) {

    private var last = 0.0

    companion object {
        lateinit var texture: Texture
    }

    override fun init(window: Window) {
        super.init(window)
        this.loadVertex(this::class.java.getResource("/assets/shaders/vertex.glsl")!!.file)
        this.loadFragment(this::class.java.getResource("/assets/shaders/fragment.glsl")!!.file)

        this.validate()

        texture = Texture("/assets/textures/no_texture.png")
        texture.load()
        texture.upload()

        val obj = GameObject("Object", 100, 100, 256, 256)
        obj.add(SpriteRenderer(Color.WHITE))
        this.addObject(obj)
    }

    override fun preRender() {
        super.preRender()
        val dTime = last / Time.now()
        this.last = Time.now()
        this.shader.setUniform("textureSampler", 0)
        this.camera.x -= dTime.toFloat() / 5f
    }
}
```

**Texture**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.texture

import de.matthiasmann.twl.utils.PNGDecoder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class Texture(val path: String) {
    val logger = LogManager.getLogger()!!
    val decoder = PNGDecoder(this::class.java.getResourceAsStream(this.path))
    val width = this.decoder.width
    val height = this.decoder.height
    lateinit var buffer: ByteBuffer
        private set
    var id = -1
        private set
        get() {
            if (field == -1) throw NullPointerException("Texture id of ${this.path} requested before texture was loaded.")
            else return field
        }

    companion object {
        const val BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4
    }

    fun load() {
        this.logger.debug("Loading texture from ${this.path}.")

        this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.decoder.width * this.decoder.height * BYTES_PER_PIXEL)
        this.decoder.decode(this.buffer, this.decoder.width * BYTES_PER_PIXEL, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA)
        this.buffer.flip()

        this.logger.debug("Loaded texture from ${this.path}.")
    }

    fun upload() {
        this.logger.debug("Uploading texture from ${this.path}")

        this.id = GL30.glGenTextures()
        GL30.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.id)
        GL30.glPixelStorei(GL30.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        GL30.glTexImage2D(
            GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA, this.width, this.height,
            0, GL30.GL_RGBA, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.buffer
        )
        GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        this.logger.debug("Uploaded texture from ${this.path}")
    }

    fun bind() = GL30.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.id)

    fun cleanup() = GL30.glDeleteTextures(this.id)
}
```

**Renderer**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.ShaderProgram
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window.Scene
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.objects.GameObject
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.objects.components.SpriteRenderer
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

class Renderer(val scene: Scene) {
    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger()

    companion object {
        const val MAX_BATCH_SIZE = 1024
    }

    private val batches = mutableListOf<RenderBatch>()

    fun add(obj: GameObject) {
        val sprite = obj.get(SpriteRenderer::class.java)
        if (sprite == null) {
            this.logger.warn("Tried to add GameObject '${obj.name}' to Renderer without a SpriteRenderer.")
            return
        }

        var added = false
        for (batch in this.batches) {
            if (batch.hasRoom) {
                batch.addSprite(sprite)
                added = true
                break
            }
        }

        if (!added) {
            val batch = RenderBatch(this.batches.size, this.scene, MAX_BATCH_SIZE)
            this.batches.add(batch)
            batch.addSprite(sprite)
        }
    }

    fun render() = this.batches.forEach { it.render() }
}
```

**Renderbatch**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window.DebugScene
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.window.Scene
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.objects.components.SpriteRenderer
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30

class RenderBatch(val index: Int, val scene: Scene, val maxBatchSize: Int = 1024) {
    /*
     *  Vertex
     * --------
     * Pos              Color                           Texture
     * float, float,    float, float, float, float,     float, float
     */
    companion object {
        private const val POSITION_SIZE = 2
        private const val POSITION_OFFSET = 0
        private const val COLOR_SIZE = 4
        private const val COLOR_OFFSET = POSITION_OFFSET + POSITION_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
        private const val TEXTURE_SIZE = 2
        private const val TEXTURE_OFFSET = COLOR_OFFSET + TEXTURE_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
        private const val VERTEX_SIZE = POSITION_SIZE + COLOR_SIZE + TEXTURE_SIZE
        private const val VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
    }

    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger()!!
    private val vertices = FloatArray(this.maxBatchSize * VERTEX_SIZE * 4) // 4 Vertices per sprite.
    private val sprites = arrayOfNulls<SpriteRenderer>(this.maxBatchSize)
    var numSprites = 0
        private set
    var hasRoom = true
        private set
    private var vao = -1
    private var vbo = -1

    init {
        this.logger.debug("Initializing new RenderBatch with max size of ${this.maxBatchSize} with ID #${this.index}!")
        this.scene.shader.validate()

        // Generate and bind VAO
        this.vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays()
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(this.vao)

        // Allocate space for vertices
        this.vbo = GL30.glGenBuffers()
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo)
        GL30.glBufferData(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertices.size * Float.SIZE_BYTES.toLong(), GL30.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        // Create and upload indices buffer

        val ebo = GL30.glGenBuffers()
        val indices = this.generateIndices()
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
        GL30.glBufferData(GL30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL30.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        // Enable the buffer attribute pointers
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, POSITION_SIZE, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES, POSITION_OFFSET.toLong())
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, COLOR_SIZE, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES, COLOR_OFFSET.toLong())
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(2, TEXTURE_SIZE, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES, TEXTURE_OFFSET.toLong())
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
    }

    fun render() {
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo)
        GL30.glBufferSubData(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, this.vertices)

        GL30.glActiveTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GL30.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, DebugScene.texture.id)

        this.scene.uploadCameraDataToGPU()

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(this.vao)

        // Two triangles per square. Three indices per triangle.
        GL30.glDrawElements(GL30.GL_TRIANGLES, this.numSprites * 6, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0)

        //     this.scene.shader.detach()
    }

    fun addSprite(sprite: SpriteRenderer): Boolean {
        if (!this.hasRoom) return false
        this.sprites[this.numSprites] = sprite
        this.loadVertexProperties(this.numSprites)

        this.logger.debug("Added new SpriteRenderer with index ${this.numSprites} to RenderBatch #${this.index}.")

        this.numSprites++

        if (this.numSprites >= this.maxBatchSize) this.hasRoom = false
        return true
    }

    private fun generateIndices(): IntArray {
        // Two triangles per square. Three indices per triangle.
        val elements = IntArray(this.maxBatchSize * 6)
        for (i in 0 until maxBatchSize) {
            val offsetIndex = 6 * i
            val offset = 4 * i

            // Element order: 3 2 0 0 2 1
            // Triangle 1
            elements[offsetIndex] = offset + 3
            elements[offsetIndex + 1] = offset + 2
            elements[offsetIndex + 2] = offset + 0

            // Triangle 2
            elements[offsetIndex + 3] = offset + 0
            elements[offsetIndex + 4] = offset + 2
            elements[offsetIndex + 5] = offset + 1
        }
        return elements
    }

    private fun loadVertexProperties(index: Int) {
        val sprite = this.sprites[index]!!
        // Find offset within array (4 vertices per sprite)
        var offset = index * 4 * VERTEX_SIZE

        var xAdd = 1f
        var yAdd = 1f
        for (i in 0..3) {
            when (i) {
                1 -> yAdd = 0f
                2 -> xAdd = 0f
                3 -> yAdd = 1f
                else -> {}
            }

            // Position
            this.vertices[offset] = sprite.obj!!.boundings.x + (xAdd * sprite.obj!!.boundings.width)
            this.vertices[offset + 1] = sprite.obj!!.boundings.y + (yAdd * sprite.obj!!.boundings.height)

            // Color
            this.vertices[offset + 2] = sprite.color.red
            this.vertices[offset + 3] = sprite.color.green
            this.vertices[offset + 4] = sprite.color.blue
            this.vertices[offset + 5] = sprite.color.alpha

            // Texture
            this.vertices[offset + 6] = xAdd
            this.vertices[offset + 7] = yAdd

            offset += VERTEX_SIZE
        }
    }
}
```

**Color**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.util

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
import kotlin.math.min

class Color(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float) {

    val red: Float
    val green: Float
    val blue: Float
    val alpha: Float

    init {
        this.red = this.check(red)
        this.green = this.check(green)
        this.blue = this.check(blue)
        this.alpha = this.check(alpha)
    }

    companion object {
        val randomProvider = { ThreadLocalRandom.current() }
        fun random(): Color {
            return Color(
                this.randomProvider().nextFloat(),
                this.randomProvider().nextFloat(),
                this.randomProvider().nextFloat(),
                this.randomProvider().nextFloat()
            )
        }

        val WHITE = Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
        val GRAY = Color(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1f)
        val BLACK = Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        val RED = Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        val GREEN = Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f)
        val BLUE = Color(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f)
        val MAGENTA = Color(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f)
        val YELLOW = Color(1f, 1f, 0f, 1f)
        val CYAN = Color(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
    }

    constructor(color: Color) : this(color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)
    constructor(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float) : this(red, green, blue, 1f)

    fun add(color: Color) = this.add(color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)

    fun add(red: Float = 0f, green: Float = 0f, blue: Float = 0f, alpha: Float = 0f) = Color(
        min(this.red + red, 1f),
        min(this.green + green, 1f),
        min(this.blue + blue, 1f),
        min(this.alpha + alpha, 1f)
    )

    private fun check(color: Float): Float {
        if (!(0f..1f).contains(color))
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot assign color value smaller than 0 or greater than 1 ($color).")
        else return color
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Color

        if (red != other.red) return false
        if (green != other.green) return false
        if (blue != other.blue) return false
        if (alpha != other.alpha) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = red.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + green.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + blue.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + alpha.hashCode()
        return result
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Color(red=$red, green=$green, blue=$blue, alpha=$alpha)"
    }
}
```

**ShaderProgram**:

```
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.exceptions.gui.ShaderCompilationException
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.types.FragmentShader
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.types.VertexShader
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.joml.Matrix4f
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil
import java.io.File

class ShaderProgram(val name: String) {
    var id = GL30.glCreateProgram()
        private set
    var vertex: VertexShader? = null
        private set
    var fragment: FragmentShader? = null
        private set
    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger()!!

    fun validate(): Boolean {
        val result = this.validateQuiet()
        return if (result != 0) {
            logger.warn(ShaderCompilationException("Shader validation for shader '${this.name}' failed ($result)."))
            false
        } else true
    }

    fun validateQuiet(): Int {
        var error = 0
        if (this.id == -1) error += 1
        if (this.vertex == null) error += 2
        if (this.fragment == null) error += 4
        return error
    }

    fun loadVertex(file: File) {
        this.vertex = VertexShader()
        this.vertex!!.create(file)
        this.vertex!!.attach(this)
    }

    fun loadFragment(file: File) {
        this.fragment = FragmentShader()
        this.fragment!!.create(file)
        this.fragment!!.attach(this)
    }

    fun link() = GL30.glLinkProgram(this.id)

    fun unlink() = GL30.glLinkProgram(0)

    fun use() = GL30.glUseProgram(this.id)

    fun detach() = GL30.glUseProgram(0)

    fun cleanup() {
        this.unlink()
        GL30.glDeleteProgram(this.id)
        this.id = -1
    }

    fun setUniform(varName: String, value: Matrix4f) {
        val varLoc = GL30.glGetUniformLocation(this.id, varName)
        val buf = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(4 * 4)
        value.get(buf)
        GL30.glUniformMatrix4fv(varLoc, false, buf)
    }

    fun setUniform(varName: String, value: Int) {
        val varLoc = GL30.glGetUniformLocation(this.id, varName)
        GL30.glUniform1i(varLoc, value)
    }
}
```

**Shader**:

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30
import java.io.File
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

open class Shader(val type: ShaderType) {
    var id: Int = -1
        protected set
    var program: ShaderProgram? = null
        private set
    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger()!!

    fun create(file: File): Int {
        val src = file.readText(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        this.id = GL30.glCreateShader(this.type.glType)
        GL30.glShaderSource(this.id, src)
        GL30.glCompileShader(this.id)

        if (GL30.glGetShaderi(this.id, GL30.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0)
            logger.error(
                "Failed to compile ${type.name.uppercase()}-SHADER. " +
                        "Error code: ${GL30.glGetShaderInfoLog(this.id)}"
            )

        return id
    }

    fun attach(program: ShaderProgram) {
        this.program = program
        GL30.glAttachShader(this.program!!.id, this.id)
    }

    fun detach() {
        if (this.program == null) return
        GL30.glDetachShader(this.program!!.id, this.id)
        this.program = null
    }
}
```

**VertexShader**: (Class)

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.types

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.Shader
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.ShaderType

class VertexShader : Shader(ShaderType.VERTEX)
```

**FragmentShader**: (Class)

```kotlin
package com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.types

import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.Shader
import com.github.trqhxrd.untitledgame.engine.gui.rendering.shader.ShaderType

class FragmentShader : Shader(ShaderType.FRAGMENT)
```

**Vertex Shader**:

```c
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexture;

uniform mat4 uProjection;
uniform mat4 uView;

out vec4 fColor;
out vec2 fTexture;

void main() {
    fColor = aColor;
    fTexture = aTexture;
    gl_Position =  uProjection * uView * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**:

```c
#version 330

in vec4 fColor;
in vec2 fTexture;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = texture2D(textureSampler, fTexture);
}
```

Also [this](https://github.com/Trqhxrd/Untitled-Game/commit/086ef7a3c93ca292563af654eb603a4a90490d99) (This is already the commit with the error) is the GitHub repository if I'm missing any classes.

Comment: The debug messages you get are unrelated to your problem. They just inform you which memory is used, but they aren't errors.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

> ```
> companion object {
>     private const val POSITION_SIZE = 2
>     private const val POSITION_OFFSET = 0
>     private const val COLOR_SIZE = 4
>     private const val COLOR_OFFSET = POSITION_OFFSET + POSITION_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
>     private const val TEXTURE_SIZE = 2
>     private const val TEXTURE_OFFSET = COLOR_OFFSET + TEXTURE_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
>     private const val VERTEX_SIZE = POSITION_SIZE + COLOR_SIZE + TEXTURE_SIZE
>     private const val VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
> }
> ```

Your `TEXTURE_OFFSET` is completely wrong, it should be

```
private const val TEXTURE_OFFSET = COLOR_OFFSET + COLOR_SIZE * Float.SIZE_BYTES
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I just tried it with that fix and it's not rendering anything again. Any other idea? I'm currently systematically removing parts of the rendering (background, camera, etc.) to check if it gets any better.